# Working with vector values in C++ CLI

Tags: visual-c++, vector, c++-cli

Here is my header file in Visual C++ Express 2010 (note the last line):

```
/* custom class header to communicate with LynxMotion robot arm */

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;

public ref class LynxRobotArm
{
public:
    LynxRobotArm();
    ~LynxRobotArm();
    void connectToSerialPort(String^ portName, int baudRate);
    void disconnectFromSerialPort();
    void setCurrentPosition(int channel, int position);
    int getCurrentPosition(int channel);
    void moveToPosition(int channel, int position);

private:
    void initConnection();
    SerialPort^ serialPort;
    array<String^> ^serialPortNames;
    String^ portName;
    int baudRate;
    std::vector<int> *currentPosition;
};
```

I try to assign a value to the vector by using this function;

```
void LynxRobotArm::setCurrentPosition(int channel, int position)
{
    currentPosition[channel] = position;
}
```

The compiler gives me an error C2679: 
`binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

I looked up at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1925w4w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and they say:

> To use the operator, you must overload it for the specified type or define a conversion to a type for which the operator is defined.

I tried using `currentPosition.at(channel) = position` but it did not make a difference.

I am stuck... quite new to pointers, noted that using `std::vector<int> currentPosition;` instead of `std::vector<int> *currentPosition;` does not compile.

How should my set-function work? (will try getter afterwards..)

Comment: The correct syntax is `(*currentPosition)[channel]`.  You are getting yourself into trouble mixing native with managed types, your next problem is making sure the vector pointer is properly initialized and destroyed.  You *have* to add a finalizer.  There's no visible reason that field couldn't be a `List<int>^` or an `array<int>^`.

Comment: Okay, let me try a `List<int>^` tomorrow.

Comment: Tried, did not work as intended. Probably my fault.. guess you are right, and as a beginner in VC++ I find it hard to understand what part is general C++ and what is CLI related. For now I will take a dirty approach and hardcode several channels (just 5) instead of using a neat array / vector / List. Might look at this later...